# Javascript pdf file download prompt with IE7 onwords

Tags: javascript, file, download

In javascript want to show a file download prompt for pdf download which works on IE7 & above, chrome as well as firefox.

Comment: And... Are you having an issue? What have you attempted?

Comment: I did tried using Blob but its not supported on IE7 so getting an error saying blob is not a function.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: Can we chat to discuss the same?

Comment: Sure, send me a link

Comment: Sorry, but not aware of how to create the same. Can you help on the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146355/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-jinish-shah).